# How to correctly extend variable __all__ in a __init__.py?

Tags: python, import

I'm confused when I tried write myself __init__.py after saw the code in numpy\__init__.py library.

Here is numpy\__init__.py code snippet

```
__all__.extend(['__version__', 'pkgload', 'PackageLoader',
           'show_config'])
__all__.extend(core.__all__)
__all__.extend(_mat.__all__)
__all__.extend(lib.__all__)
__all__.extend(['linalg', 'fft', 'random', 'ctypeslib', 'ma'])
```

And My directory structure is:

app/

......test.py

......lib1\

............ __init__.py

............ Lib1File.py

............ sublib1\

............ ............ __init__.py

............ ............ SubLib1File.py

The code in test.py is

```
from lib1 import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result1 = Lib1File.add(10, 15)    # a simple function in Lib1File.py
    print(result1)
    result2 = Sublib1File.mul(10,15)  # a simple function in Sublib1File.py
    print(result2)
```

The code in lib1\__init__.py is

```
from . import sublib1
__all__ = ["Lib1File"]
__all__.extend(sublib1.__all__)
print(__all__)                 # it can print ['Lib1File', 'Sublib1File'] on console
```

The code in lib1\sublib1\__init__.py is

```
__all__ = ["Sublib1File"]
```

But when I ran test.py, I got a error

***File "test.py", line 1, in module from lib1 import *. AttributeError: module 'lib1' has no attribute 'Sublib1File'***

My questions are

1. Why I get this error even if `__all__ = ['Lib1File', 'Sublib1File']` in lib1\__init__.py?
2. How should I fix it if I still just use one import `from lib1 import *`?
3. If we cannot solve question 2, what's the purpose of `__all__.extend(...)` in numpy\__init__?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take another look at numpy's top-level `__init__` module you'll see that for each `from . import xyz` that's used to extend `__all__` there's a corresponding `from .xyz import *`.

Adding a name to a module's `__all__` is meaningless if the corresponding object isn't either defined in the module itself or imported from somewhere else. The `__all__` statement doesn't import anything on it's own.

Add `from .sublib1 import *` below `from . import sublib1` in `lib1/__init__.py`.

Also see: [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. But I still have no idea how to fix the problem. Could you give me more specific modification? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extending @wyatts answer, add the following line in `lib1/__init__.py`:

```
from .sublib1 import *
```

To make the example work.

Answer (score 0):

you are right @Wyatt, @MegaIng.

I post my answer here for the three questions, just in case others need it.

Q1. Why I get this error even if `__all__ = ['Lib1File', 'Sublib1File']` in lib1__init__.py?

A1. Because you just add module name to __all__. But it actually does not have `SublibFile` module in `lib1` directory. So python cannot find the definition of `SublibFile` module just by the module name.

Q2. How should I fix it if I still just use one `import from lib1 import *`?

A2. Add one line `from .sublib1 import *` in `lib1/__init__.py`. This will put modules that are defined in `__all__` in `lib1\sublib1\__init__.py` to `lib\` package so that python can find correspondence module definition by the module name.

Q3.  What's the purpose of `__all__.extend(...)` in `numpy\__init__`?

A3. In order to extend `__all__` flexibility.